# how to keep redirection history of duplicates

Tags: redirect, scrapy, duplicates

scrapys duplication filter ignores already seen urls/requests. So far, so good.

---

**The Problem**

Even if a request is dropped I still want to keep the redirection history.

Example:

- Request 1 : B
- Request 2 : A --301--> B

In this case request 2 is dropped without letting me know that it is a 'hidden' duplicate of request 1.

---

**Attempts**

I already tried to catch the signal request_dropped. This works but I don't see a possibility to sent an item to the pipeline from the handler.

---

Best regards and thanks for your help :)

Raphael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to handle those 'hidden' redirects:

1. Catch the signal 'request_dropped' from 'from_crawler':

```
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(YourSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.on_request_dropped, signal=signals.request_dropped)
        return spider
```

2. Use 'self.crawler.engine.scraper.enqueue_scrape' to route the response to a callback which can yield items. enqueue_scrape expects a response so you can simply create a dummy response from the dropped request (I used TextResponse for this). With this response you can also define the callback.

```
    def on_request_dropped(self, request, spider):
        """ handle dropped request (duplicates) """

        request.callback = self.parse_redirection_from_dropped_request
        response = TextResponse(url=request.url, request=request)
        self.crawler.engine.scraper.enqueue_scrape(request=request, 
                                                   response=response, spider=self)
```

3. Process the redirection history of the dropped request within the callback you defined. From here you can handle things exactly like within the regular parse callback.

```
def parse_redirection_from_dropped_request(self, response):
    ...
    yield item
```

I hope this might help you if you stumble upon the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [DUPEFILTER_DEBUG](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-debug)

Set it to `True` in `settings.py` file and you will see all URLs that were ignored because of being duplicate

Comment: Hi Umair, thanks for your answer. By using DUPEFILTER_DEBUG I would enable the log for all ignored requests but I need to process them and store the redirection history.